# How to move outlet in wall?

Tags: electrical

I'd like to move an outlet that is in a wall between a finished spaced and an unfinished space.  Right now my TV is hanging on a wall and connected to an outlet that is too high for my tastes.  I'd like to move it down maybe 18-24".  I know that I could put in a junction box to extend the wires down, but from what I've read you can't have a junction box buried in a wall.  I could put a blank template on the existing outlet, but that'd just be ugly.

Since the current box is in a half finished wall (i.e. it's in a wall with a workshop on one side that's not finished), is there a way that I can extend the power cables and drywall off the old hole?

My guess would be that I could take out the old box and put in a junction box, but instead of the "facing" towards the finished space, I could just put the access panel part toward the unfinished space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### That is fine

You can do as you desire -- take the old j-box out and replace it with one facing into the unfinished space.  I'd use a 4" square junction box and mount it so the front lip is flush with the edge of the studs -- this way, if you want to finish the unfinished space later, you can simply slap a mud ring on the box in place of the existing cover, then put a new cover on after the drywall's up.